# Atualizar valor de célula no Datagridview em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá!

Ao clicar em um botão, preciso que atualize o valor de uma célula no `datagridview`.

segue o código que tentei mas não funcionou.

```
  private void btnAcesso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvLista.SelectedRows)
        {
            dgvLista.Rows[item.Index].Cells["acesso"].Value = "S";
        }
    }
```

Tem que atualizar da linha selecionada.

Obs: Entra no `foreach` mas não atualiza.

Obrigado.

Preenchimento da grid:

```
 var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = lstMenuAux;
            dgvLista.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Você utilizou o `datagridview.DataSource` para inserir os dados na grade?

Comment: Sim, com a ajuda do `DataBinding`

Comment: Você deve alterar no model que você setou no datasource, por exemplo `ItemDataGridView obj = (ItemDataGridView)dgvLista.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;`
                `obj.acesso = "S";`, lembrando que ItemDataGridView é a classe que você usou para setar no datasource

Comment: Não entendi.. da onde vc tirou esse `ItemDataGridView` não aparece aqui

Comment: Substitui o ItemDataGridView pela classe que você usou para jogar no datasource do datagridview

Comment: Poste o código de como você preenche o datagridview

Comment: Ok, postei, editei na pergunta

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `lstMenuAux`?

Comment: É um objeto.. um model.. uma lista de objetos

Comment: Sim, jovem, isso eu sei. Quero que você digite o nome do tipo aqui, pra eu poder escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Desculpa... List<MenuModel>

Comment: Tenta trocar o ItemDataGridView por MenuModel

Comment: Tentei Marco, porém não funcionou.. Está no update da pergunta

Comment: Marco.. deu certo! Obrigado!